# Is there a better looping mechanism for this code that won't throw a code analysis warning?

Tags: vb.net, optimization

I recently upgraded to VB.NET 2019 and have been going through code analysis to clean everything up in a database program to what MS considers "best practice".  This bit of code and a couple just like it I'm having a issue with.  The analysis says "Value assigned to 'x' is never used" which is true but I'm not sure of a better way of writing it.  Long story short a user can select multiple items in a gridview then run a report and the query is built based on that using or statements.  It runs through what is selected and adds to the query.  If only one item is selected it just does the selected one (x=0) and if more are selected its adding a OR then the info.  Code is cleaned up for simplicity:

```
Dim x As Integer = 0
For x = 0 To myGridView.SelectedRowsCount - 1
    If x = 0 Then
        mySQL += "{" & myQuery & ".CompanyID} =" & CInt(myGridView.SelectedRows(x))
    Else
        mySQL += " OR {" & myQuery & ".CompanyID} =" & CInt(myGridView.SelectedRows(x))
    End If
Next
```

Is there a better way to do this so it doesn't throw that error?

Comment: Maybe: For x As Integer = 0 To myGridView.SelectedRowsCount - 1  instead of dim the variable. You could also use a StringBuilder, parametrize your query if possible and use an IN statement.

Comment: That worked perfectly, is a simple change, and reads just as easy.  Thanks!

Comment: As for using a parameter list any code with user input does that but this example and other things with no user input (mostly report printing where people just select existing options) still use a standard SQL calls.  This problem was the last of 500+ code recommendations that are now cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual warning might be because you initialize the integer but then use it in the For loop. Just initialize it in the For loop.

```
' Remove this line: Dim x As Integer = 0

For x As Integer = 0 To myGridView.SelectedRowsCount - 1
    ' ...
Next
```

Comment: I'm not even sure you need the `As Integer`, I think the type will be inferred.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off using a conditional statement as well as SQL's [IN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_in.asp). Basically you'd check if `myGridView.SelectedRowsCount` equals 0, if so then you'd display an error. Then you'd have an ElseIf that checks if `myGridView.SelectedRowsCount` equals 1, if so then you'd use the equals operator. Finally you'd have an Else statement that joins the values using a comma as the glue.

Take a look at this example:

```
If myGridView.SelectedRowsCount = 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("There are no rows selected. Please select one or more rows.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.Ok, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
ElseIf myGridView.SelectedRowsCount = 1 Then
    mySQL &= "{" & myQuery & ".CompanyID} = " myGridView.SelectedRows(0)
Else
    mySQL &= "{" & myQuery & ".CompanyID} IN (" & String.Join(", ", myGridView.SelectedRows) & ")"
End If
```

Please keep in mind that this is pseudo-code and you may need to make adjustments, in particular I don't know if `SelectedRows` or `SelectedRows(0)` returns a String array/literal.

P.S. You may want to consider using a parameterized query. It would not be difficult to implement one using the same concept that I'm using above.

Comment: The button for running the report doesn't enable until at least one item is selected and disabled if it drops back to 0 items so that's covered.  There could also be 30 things selected so a loop is indeed needed.

Comment: @Allan - Do you understand what my code is doing an why there is no need for a loop?

Comment: I believe so, it should pull each selected row and add the comma between for one big "IN x,x,x,x" statement.  But the gridview I'm using is a custom control and I'm actually pulling one of the multiple fields out of the SelectedRows and doing some stuff to it.  It's my fault for simplifying the code for the question....the actual code isn't as pretty.  Using a modification of your code may in the end be easier and get rid of the loop completely but for now the slight change works.

Comment: @David you don't need this clause and corresponding code at all `ElseIf myGridView.SelectedRowsCount = 1 Then` since 1) Join will return the single element un-delimited, and 2) the sql `WHERE ... IN ( ... )` syntax will work for a single element as well. But +1 to this answer because it is an all-around vast improvement.